# Read file packaged with Chrome extension in content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension that needs to package an XML file (a trie data structure) and be able to read that file from the content script. So the content script will instantiate the trie after reading the data from the XML file every time the extension is loaded.

How to read this XML file through content script (or background page)? Do I need to use localStorage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple ajax request to the XML file should give you the XML DOM nodes:

```
function request(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xhr.readyState != 4)
                return;

            if (xhr.responseXML) {
                console.debug(xhr.responseXML);
            }
        }

        xhr.onerror = function(error) {
            console.debug(error);
        }

        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

function init() {
    request("sample.xml");
}
```

You would need to use a js-based xml parser or write your own. It might be easier to save your data as a JSON object.

Comment: Thanks Shrey! This works like a charm for background pages but not for content scripts (as they run in the context of the webpage and end up GETing http://some webpage.com /sample.xml). Turns out that I need the trie in the background page only, not in the content script.  

Initially I was not sure where I'd use the trie, so output it in XML but JSON is a better choice for js. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, I was expecting chrome.* like APIs for accessing files packaged with extensions; Looks like they don't exist.

Comment: Yeah, it is slightly counter-intuitive. If you do need the data in the content script, you can always pass it from the background page using sendMessage.

Comment: Yes, I am communicating between the two pages using chrome.tabs.sendRequest and chrome.extension.sendRequest(). Thanks :)

Comment: You can access the file from content scripts too, but you need to specify it in "web_accessible_resources" in manifest.js file.