# Read a Text File into array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text, google-chrome-extension, content-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read file packaged with Chrome extension in content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550383/read-file-packaged-with-chrome-extension-in-content-script)

I want to develop a small extension that needs to do the following:

1. Read a text file (that comes packaged with the extension)
2. Save each line as a string in an array
3. Check the page's URL to see if it's one of the pages it's compatible with.
4. Read the page to find words that are present in the array
5. Make these words links to a google search.

So, steps 3 to 5, I have some idea of how to do, but 1 and 2 are getting me lost.
I was thinking of getting the file through `chrome.extension.getURL("files/mytext.txt");`, but this only gives me the file, doesn't read it.

Thanks!
Edits: Formatting

Comment: Unsure, have you had a look at this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550383/read-file-packaged-with-chrome-extension-in-content-script ?

Comment: 32,187,341,467,548,770,1128,1590,1593,1712,1713,1793,1796,1832,1893,2016,2063,2075,2187,2228,2291,2455,2580,2836,2847,2862,2873,2991,3035,3156,3158,3199,3315,3357,3379,3389,3471,3477,3491,3506,3561,3679,3775,3878,3883,3937,3949,4215,4229,4269,4676,4694,4706,4776,4857,4990,4999,5097,5437,5623,5648,5734,5740,5825,5832,5896,5907,5954,5994,6065,6111,6215,6247,6330,6401,6426,6768,7001,7593,7710,7744,7886,8310,8351,8386,9010,9015,9102,9309,9331,9834,9848,10343,10423,10881,11052,11125,11165,11177,11261,11368,11747,11869,11952,12060,12382

Comment: 12394,12600,12747,12827,12840,12843,13148,13189,13277,13360,13396,13497,13651,13655,13706,13755,13808,13815,14042,14089,14144,14293,14338,14347,14417,14472,14495,14572,14746,14777,14838,14892,14909

Comment: 32,187,548,1796,1832,2063,2291,2836,3156,3158,3471,3477,4215,4706,4857,4990,5740,5832,6111,6247,9010,9102,9331,10423,13277

Answer (score 0):

`I'm not sure this is the best way, I know little about extension programming, but if you have a URL a XMLHttpRequst should work.

```
var fileURL = chrome.extension.getURL("files/mytext.txt"); 
var xmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest()
xmlreq.open("GET", fileURL, false) //false makes it syncronous, we'll just wait till it's done
xmlreq.send()
//The file should be in xmlreq.responseText array
lineArray = xmlreq.responseText.split("\n") //standard splitting by linebreaks
```

There might be some error checking to do there, but that should be the basic protocol.  You could also do syncronous, but if you're just loading a fairly text file, unless it's massive, asyncronous shouldn't be an issue.

EDIT: forgot `xmlreq.send()` the first time.

Comment: You mean "false makes it **synchronous**".  However, note that support for synchronous XHR is going to be phased out of Chrome extensions (or at least apps -- "apps" and "extensions" have been virtually the same thing in the past, but now Google is doing a major overhaul of packaged apps, so we'll see.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix that.  I always get those backwards.